# read the result of a client file from socket programming in a new python program file

Tags: python-3.x

i write a client-server code in python to send and receive data between my raspi and my phone. now i have a client code (`client.py`) with the buffer output `reply = s.recv(1024)`

i create another file with name `program.py` and i want to define a function in it that be able to print the value of buffer `reply` and process it.

```
import client

class base(obj)

def get_reply(self):

print(client.reply)
```

but it gives syntax error.
could some on help me with that?

Comment: You need a colon `:` after the class definition, and you should also fix your indentation.

Comment: isn't there any other problem? i receive this error ImportError: No module named 'client'
i put both file in the same folder. how can i fix this error.

Comment: when i execute file program.py it runs the server (i import client instead of server)and and receive data from client but it doesn't run "get_reply" function and then wait in listening loop of server.now i want to know why program.py execute the server from the first line while i point to the receive line in the server. second question is if i use thread in server could it be helpful? if yes how can i use it? i mean program.py is no socket so i cant make a new thread in server and send data to program.py. please help me with this problem.